# Add ButtonGroup to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, buttongroup

```
JPanel.add(ButtonGroup);
```

Is not working. I MUST add it to a JPanel because I am using tabs.
This is getting really frustrating.I hace not found a way yet

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html

Comment: What do you mean JPanel.add(ButtonGroup)?

Can you share more code sample how are you initializing JPanel, buttonGroup etc?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As ButtonGroup is not a component, you cannot add your ButtonGroup to a JPanel. Instead add your buttons to your JPanel, e.g:

```
JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
btn1 = new JRadioButton("btn1 ");btn1.setSelected(true);
btn2 = new JRadioButton("btn2 ");
group.add(btn1 );
group.add(btn2 );

jPanel.add(btn1);
jPanel.add(btn2).
```

Hope it will be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The ButtonGroup class creates only a logical radio button selection group, not a physical one, and is responsible for ensuring that only one button is selected (by deselecting others in the group).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).